# log4j logging hierarchy order

Tags: logging, log4j

What is the hierarchy of log4j logging?

```
DEBUG
INFO
WARN
ERROR
FATAL
```

Which one provides the highest logging which would be helpful to troubleshoot issues?
Can any one provide the order or hierarchy in which logging take place from highest to lowest?
Thanks!

Answer (score 415):

This table might be helpful for you:

[image: Log Level]

Going down the first column, you will see how the log works in each level. i.e for **WARN**, (**FATAL, ERROR and WARN**) will be visible. For **OFF**, nothing will be visible.

Comment: The terms *visibility* and *item* are not self explanatory. I see that the official documentation is also vague on this. The output method such as `error`, `info`, `debug`, etc. of the logger assigns a priority/severity level to the logging message. If the logging really takes effect (the message will be visible) depends on the effective logging level of the logger being used.

Comment: link broken. please fix or remove

Comment: Although this answers the question (that's just asking for the "hierarchy order"), I finally downvoted for your poor terminology: *going down*, *"visibility" works*, *item*. Didn't you wish to explain how logger configuration affects the actual logging (passing log events)? *Please* consider another update. BTW: the table in the [official documentation](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html#LoggerConfig) (at the end of the section) differs in treating `OFF` and `ALL`, well, after reading some of the source (not finding special cases) I doubt that their table is correct.

Comment: Thank you Wolf, I have updated the answer according to your comments.

Comment: I think this is an excellent visualization of the log levels and the expected log message types that would be output for a specific logger level setting.  My only suggestion might be to have alternating row colors to guide the viewer that the chart should be interpreted by row rather than column.  (i.e. the rows represent logger levels and the columns represent log message types that would be present)

Answer (score 165):

Use the force, read the source (excerpt from the `Priority` and `Level` class compiled, TRACE level was introduced in version 1.2.12):

```java
public final static int OFF_INT = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
public final static int FATAL_INT = 50000;
public final static int ERROR_INT = 40000;
public final static int WARN_INT  = 30000;
public final static int INFO_INT  = 20000;
public final static int DEBUG_INT = 10000;
public static final int TRACE_INT = 5000; 
public final static int ALL_INT = Integer.MIN_VALUE;
```

or the [log4j API for the `Level` class](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html), which makes it quite clear.

When the library decides whether to print a certain statement or not, it computes the effective level of the responsible `Logger` object (based on configuration) and compares it with the `LogEvent`'s level (depends on which method was used in the code – *trace/debug/.../fatal*). If `LogEvent`'s level is greater or equal to the `Logger`'s level, the `LogEvent` is sent to appender(s) – "printed". At the core, it all boils down to an integer comparison and this is where these constants come to action.

Answer (score 63):

```
OFF
FATAL
ERROR
WARN
INFO
DEBUG
TRACE
ALL
```

Comment: check the code where are integer variables for proof http://www.docjar.com/html/api/org/apache/log4j/Level.java.html

Comment: at your link it said that "ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF" and it perfectly the same as I said

Comment: Venn diagram
OFF() ALL(TRACE(DEBUG(INFO(WARN(ERROR(FATAL))))))

Comment: @Mike on [log4j Logging Levels](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/log4j/log4j_logging_levels.htm "log4j Logging Levels") they use **alphabetic order in the first table**. Except for the missing `trace`, they later correctly state that `ALL < DEBUG < INFO < WARN < ERROR < FATAL < OFF` (wherein `<` means less important)

Answer (score 28):

Hierarchy of log4j logging levels are as follows in Highest to Lowest order :

- TRACE
- DEBUG
- INFO
- WARN
- ERROR
- FATAL
- OFF

TRACE log level provides highest logging which would be helpful to troubleshoot issues. DEBUG log level is also very useful to trouble shoot the issues.

You can also refer this link for more information about log levels : 
https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.0/manual/architecture.html

Answer (score 12):

[Taken from [http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/top-10-tips-on-logging-in-java.html]](http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2011/05/top-10-tips-on-logging-in-java.html%5d)

DEBUG is the lowest restricted java logging level and we should write everything we need to debug an application, this java logging mode should only be used on Development and Testing environment and must not be used in production environment.

INFO is more restricted than DEBUG java logging level and we should log messages which are informative purpose like Server has been started, Incoming messages, outgoing messages etc in INFO level logging in java.

WARN is more restricted than INFO java logging level and used to log warning sort of messages e.g. Connection lost between client and server. Database connection lost, Socket reaching to its limit. These messages and java logging level are almost important because you can setup alert on these logging messages in java and let your support team monitor health of your java application and react on this warning messages. In Summary WARN level is used to log warning message for logging in Java.

ERROR is the more restricted java logging level than WARN and used to log Errors and Exception, you can also setup alert on this java logging level and alert monitoring team to react on this messages. ERROR is serious for logging in Java and you should always print it.

FATAL java logging level designates very severe error events that will presumably lead the application to abort. After this mostly your application crashes and stopped.

OFF java logging level has the highest possible rank and is intended to turn off logging in Java.

Answer (score 5):

I find the term "logging level" to be a bit confusing, so I prefer to think of it like this:

- Events have a **SEVERITY** (a level). In log4j this is modelled as an integer.
- Loggers have a **THRESHOLD** (aka a LoggerConfig level, used to filter Events)

By convention, log4j defines some [Standard Log Levels](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html). In v2.x these are (in order of decending severity):
`OFF`, `FATAL`, `ERROR`, `WARN`, `INFO`, `DEBUG`, `TRACE`, `ALL`. Note that *OFF* and *ALL* are only intended as Logger threshold values, not Event severity levels). You can also add your own custom levels, and assign them a numerical value.

A Logger will ignore any events less severe than its threshold:

- A threshold of `OFF` means no logging.
- A threshold of `FATAL` means only FATAL events (or worse) are logged.
- A threshold of `ERROR` means only ERROR, FATAL (or worse) are logged.
- A threshold of `WARN` means only WARN, ERROR, FATAL (or worse) are logged.
- etc...
- A threshold of `ALL` means all events are logged (the most verbose option)

As a diagram (based on the table shown [in the log4j v2.x docs](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/architecture.html)) it looks like this:

[image: logging levels cheat sheet]

Answer (score 4):

Hierarchy order

1. ALL
2. TRACE
3. DEBUG
4. INFO
5. WARN
6. ERROR
7. FATAL
8. OFF

Answer (score 4):

To make it clear, there is no defined term like 'hierarchy' in log4j.
Yes there are different levels. For troubleshooting you have to select which level you want the logs.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Adding .NET log levels for reference

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-7.0

[image: dotnet core log level]

Answer (score 0):

The table below illustrates how Level filtering works.

In the table, the vertical header shows the level of the LogEvent you want to configure in your app settings, while the horizontal header shows the Level visibility in associated with the appropriate config.

The intersection identifies whether the LogEvent would be allowed to display logs for further processing (Yes) or discarded (No).

[image]

Answer (score -1):

TRACE --> DEBUG--> INFO -->WARN --> ERROR --> FATAL

If Log level is set for WARN. it will log all the WARN and all levels below it.(ERROR and FATAL).
If Log level is set for TRACE. it will log all the TRACE and all levels below it.(DEBUG,INFO,WARN,ERROR,FATAL).