# Logback Spring Block Log Level in Additivity

Tags: spring-boot, slf4j, spring-logback

I use spring boot app, got duplicate Error level logs, so i added `additivity="false"` which blocks other two levels.

The config as below,

```
<configuration>

    <property resource="application.properties" />

    <springProperty scope="context" name="uuid" source="uuid"/>
    <springProperty scope="context" name="environment" source="label"/>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <layout class="ch.qos.logback.classic.PatternLayout">
            <Pattern>
                %d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </Pattern>
        </layout>
    </appender>

    <appender name="ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${logging.console.level:-ERROR}</level>
        </filter>

        <filter class="com.sample.ErrorFilter">
            <criticalUUID>${uuid}</criticalUUID>
            <criticalEnvironment>${environment}</criticalEnvironment>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <appender name="WARN" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${logging.console.level:-WARN}</level>
        </filter>

        <filter class="com.sample.WarningFilter">
            <warningUUID>${uuid}</warningUUID>
            <warningEnvironment>${environment}</warningEnvironment>
        </filter>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="WARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

    <logger name="com.refinitiv" level="ERROR" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="ERROR" />
    </logger> 


</configuration>
```

any suggestion?

Any suggestions? I tried to use in application.properties

Comment: Why do you use an XML configuration?

Comment: It's an existing design, and i need to enhance some levels. Just curious, any significant difference use of XML and application.properties?

Comment: As far as I can see there is no need for the XML. application.properties is limited. So if you want to do some advanced stuff you need XML

Comment: there is encoder used inside XML and calls doLayout().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved the problem, the log hierarchy caused the issue.

```
 <appender name="ERROR" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>${logging.console.level:-WARN}</level>
        </filter>

        <filter class="com.sample.ErrorFilter">
            <criticalUUID>${uuid}</criticalUUID>
            <criticalEnvironment>${environment}</criticalEnvironment>
        </filter>
    </appender>
```

and removed `<appender name="WARN"`

Because WARN level calls ERROR in hierarchy, for reference please check below url.

[log4j logging hierarchy order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7745885/log4j-logging-hierarchy-order)